# ASP.NET MVC - Multiple Internationalization on the same page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Some co-workers and I are develping an application in which we need to have multiple languages. Our idea is to have the header's language following the user's browser settings while the content's language of the webpage will be changed when the user click somewhere.

We've tried using the usual resources technique, but it applies the translation to the whole website - and that's not the goal.

Is it possible to add multiple-language translation to the same page?

In other terms, we'd like the layout to load Resources_EN.resx while the page's content to load Resources_ES.resx.

Comment: Is the content always fixed (where a resx makes sense?) You may be able to modify the CurrentCulture within the `WebViewPage`/views.

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. It's mostly for labels, and we're not interested in creating a different page for each language.